# Image Processing - Assigning one hot encoded labels to array of images for training

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, image-processing, cntk

i'm following [this](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/CNTK_103D_MNIST_ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork.html) tutorial in CNTK applied to my own data.

I have a dataset composed 2 images per observation, and i have the train labels stored in a csv like this:

```
id,appliance
1000,8
1001,1
1002,8
1003,1
```

The label is the same for both of the 2 images i have per observation. If i take only one of 2 images kind and store them in an array i will get an array of shape (988, 128, 118), and the labels csv converted to array will have a sahpe of (988, 2), which is ok to map each label to an image.

The question is that now that i have decided to take all the images i have (the 2 per observation, instead of one) Now i have an array of images (1976, 128, 118) but my labels array is still (988, 2) the label assigning won't work because of the labels length. How do i overcome i this problem??

To do the label assigning, i'm using this function here, that assigns a label to each 15104 pixels:

```
# Save the data files into a format compatible with CNTK text reader
def savetxt(filename, data, hasLabels=True, labels=0):
    dir = os.path.dirname(filename)

    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)

    print("Saving", filename )
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        print("opened....")
        labels_ohe = list(map(' '.join, np.eye(11, dtype=np.uint).astype(str))) #for one hot encoding
        index = 0
        for row in data:            
            row_str = row.astype(str)
            if hasLabels:                               
                label_str = labels_ohe[int(labels[index])]               

            feature_str = ' '.join(row_str)

            if hasLabels:
                f.write('|labels {} |features {}\n'.format(label_str, feature_str))
            else:
                f.write('|features {}\n'.format(feature_str))

            index = index + 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The map file in cntk is defined as:

```
file_path_to_image, class_label
D:/image1.jpg, 1
D:/image2.jpg, 2
D:/image3.jpg, 1
D:/image4,jpg, 0
```

You can build a map file for the entire dataset however many observations you have.

Alternatively, if your original image array and label array already correspond in the first axis (batch axis). Then stacking them on itself will keep the correspondence in the first axis.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer! I knew about that but this isn't really what i want to do, i would like to continue using my actual working way, i have an array of images (988, 15104) and my labels array is (988, 2) the problem that when i `np.vstack` my images i have a new array of images (1976, 15104). I would like to find a way to assign these same labels to this new array. I was wondering if numpy `np.dstack` would be what i'm looking for instead `np.vstack` or `np.hstack`. Your suggested way looks interesting though. Could you please provide some example code showing how to do this?? Thank you

Comment: If you vstack you images, wouldn't you also need to vstack your label arrays to make it a one-to-one mapping?

Comment: I didn't try it because i didn't think that would work. Do you think that's the way to go? Wouldn't the labels be just concatenated? Not sure if the labels will correspond to the actual images that way

Comment: I think it would work. If your images originally correspond to the labels, stacking them in the first axis respectively will keep the correspondence.

Comment: All right @snowflake, i'll try that and if is ok i'll accept your answer. Thank you very much!! :)